# React Three Fiber: Why does my scroll event have lag to it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

In React Three Fiber, I have a react component that generates a sprite that I want to stay invariant under camera zoom. The algorithm seems to work (the size seems to not change over time), but I can visibly see it scaling as I zoom in and out.

I've seen elsewhere that does a similar thing with sprites and it seems to work without the glitchy look. I think there is some sort of lag but I'm not sure where that would be or how to fix it.

I've attached a video of how the issue looks as well: https://drive.google.com/file/d/121XPY1pB5bNJr5EYNESnyPfLDdtEeIhn/view?usp=sharing

I have attached my code of the React component. This is just fed into the canvas component as with regular React Three Fiber code:

```
function TestFunction() {
  const [scale, setScale] = useState(new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
  const map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("src/assets/Joshy.png");

  let state = useThree();
  let zoom = state.camera.zoom / 100;
  let scaler: Vector3 = new Vector3(1 / zoom, 1 / zoom, 1 / zoom);
  const handleMouseScroll = (event: WheelEvent) => {
    // Perform actions when the mouse is scrolled
    scaler.set(1 / zoom, 1 / zoom, 1 / zoom);
    setScale(scaler);
  };
  useFrame(() => {
    window.document.addEventListener("wheel", handleMouseScroll, {
      capture: true,
      passive: true,
    });
  });

  return (
    <sprite scale={scale}>
      <spriteMaterial map={map} />
    </sprite>
  );
}
```

I expect it to not have that laggy/glitchy look to it because I'm updating every frame so I'm not sure what the issue is.

What I'm looking for is something like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KtEcrikFJFYboC6LX0mFVttx2eSTia0c/view?usp=sharing
where there is no visible lag to it. The code that generates this lagless version is in plain javascript three.js.

```
const cont = document.documentElement;
const [w, h] = [cont.clientWidth - 20, cont.clientHeight - 20];
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, w / h, 0.1, 100);
camera.position.set(10, 10, 10);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(w, h);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const hlp = new THREE.AxesHelper(3);
scene.add(hlp);

const map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
  'https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200'
);
const material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
  map: map
});

const sprite_scale = 4;
const sprite = new THREE.Sprite(material);
/* sprite.scale.set(sprite_scale, sprite_scale); */
const virtual_d = sprite.position.distanceTo(camera.position) *1.4/ sprite_scale;

scene.add(sprite);

const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

const render = () => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

const animate = () => {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  render();

};

document.addEventListener('wheel', scaler);

function scaler() {
  const scale = sprite.position.distanceTo(camera.position)/2;
  console.log(sprite.position.distanceTo(camera.position) )
  console.log("CAMERA POSITION: ", camera.position)
  sprite.scale.set(scale, scale);
}

animate();
```

The logic feels the same, but the results end up very differently between plain three.js and React Three Fiber.

Comment: You’re adding a new event listener to _every_ frame in the `useFrame` hook. That’s probably the cause behind the lag. You should probably add the event listener inside `useEffect` instead.

Comment: I tried your suggestion useEffect just now, it has the same problem :/

Answer (score 1):

You are using React.

Therefore, please be careful when using 'window.document.addEventListener'.
Every time your component re-renders, a new event listener will be created, resulting in many event listeners on your page.

Instead, consider using hooks. You can find many hooks in react-three-drei.
I am strongly recommend to use react-three-drei.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleMouseScroll() {
      //do something
    }

    window.addEventListener('wheel', handleMouseScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('wheel', handleMouseScroll);
    };
  }, []);
```

In your case, you are using event listener in useFrame. Then, useFrame run 60 times per seconds. You are creating 60 numbers of event listener per seconds.